# fullcalendar disable event indent

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

[image: Event indentation]

In my project, I have specific case where I do not want events, that are overlapping, to have indentation. I've searched FC docs for something, but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how to disable this behavior for specific events?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap is probably what you're thinking of (althouh you were not specific about how you wanted it to look instead).

Comment: @ADyson both of examples have indentation of overlapping events (by overlapping events I mean time overlap). I need events to overlap each other (be on top of each other), but don't have indentation (to be in one vertical column)

Comment: For example: in above screenshot, second event (from 12:00 am) has 50% width of first event (and of event column, in general). I need it to have same width as first event

Comment: Ok. That isn't possible the way fullCalendar is written right now, unfortunately. I suggest you have a think about whether you _need_ that, or you just _want_ it. I didn't write the code but I'd guess it's done the way it is to increase the visual difference between the events so that it's easier to see that they are separate events. If they were in line with each other vertically and overlapping, with the same colour etc, I think it would be harder to see at a glance that they are different items.

Comment: But anyway I think your options are 1) accept the status quo even though it's not 100% what you wanted, 2) put in a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to see if you can get an option added in a future release, to allow it to render the events the way you've described (and depending on your skills, maybe you can contribute some code towards it), or 3) fork the project and re-write the rendering engine yourself to suit. I suspect this last one will not be a simple task however, and also you'd then be incompatible with future releases and updates.

Comment: @ADyson I was afraid this is not possible... My case is to show clickable time slots on mouseover event. Only way to do that is to just add events with specific rendering (I'm appending my class names set to them), but they must be always in the same place, because user expects them to be always in the same place to move mouse onto. I think I'll go with 2). Generally I don't have a choice. Forking will freeze my app to updates, as you said. Thank you anyway

Comment: "show clickable time slots on mouseover event"...all time slots are already clickable if you handling it via the "select" callback. You can then disable certain slots by a) putting an event (or background event) over them, b) excluding them via "businessHours" or c) having some extra rules to control it - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting for more details.

Comment: "clickable" is not problem in my case. Problem is that these events thath I'm creating are visible only on mouseover event, so it's important to make them always be in the same place in day column and to have same size. User expects such pop up slot (I call it "pop up slot", it's not the same as fullcalendar's slot. Technically it's just event) to be in the same place under the mouse cursor. So if some pop up slot receives indentation from fullcalendar, user won't know that such slot is moved somewhere else.

Comment: I'd question why you are creating hidden slots to begin with...surely that just makes it harder to use because the user has to hunt for them to find information. That doesn't sounds like a good UX in my humble opinion!